# Cannot change region of functions on flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Ive switched my functions regions from the US default and I cannot find a way to call them in flutter?

Is there a method of setting the region on the CloudFunctions instance or when you make the function calls

Thanks for the help.

---

I have managed to get this to work

```
 CloudFunctions(app: FirebaseApp.instance, region: "europe-west2").getHttpsCallable(functionName: functionName);
```

But I am no longer using the singleton.

Is this a bad solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see what's bad about it.  You're doing exactly what you have to do.  Just retain the result of `CloudFunctions(app: FirebaseApp.instance, region: "europe-west2")` in your own singleton if you want to reuse it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the official solution is to use `instanceFor`:

```
final result =
          await FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'europe-west1').httpsCallable('addRental').call(jsonEncode(data));
```

worked for me, instead of

```
final result =
          await FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('addRental').call(jsonEncode(data));
```